# C++ Linkage error with shellapi.h ShellExecuteA

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I am trying to open a file for my Engine project, but I cannot find any functions in std::filesystem to do that, so i found ShellExecuteA that do what i wanted, but when I tried to export this method from my dll to my exe, I have linkage errors:

in .h in my dll :

```
namespace FileSystem
{
    ENGINE_API void OpenFile(const char* pathFile) noexcept;
}
```

in .cpp in my dll :

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>

ENGINE_API void FileSystem::OpenFile(const char* pathFile) noexcept
{
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", (LPCSTR)pathFile, NULL, NULL, 1);
}
```

in main.cpp in my exe :

```
FileSystem::OpenFile(R"(test.h)");
```

This works only if my OpenFile method is inline, but i dont want to include Windows.h in header file.
And this works if i define the method not in dll.

The error:

Erreur  LNK2019 symbole externe non résolu __imp_ShellExecuteA référencé dans la fonction "void __cdecl FileSystem::OpenFile(char const *)" (?OpenFile@FileSystem@@YAXPEBD@Z)   Engine  C:\Users\user\Desktop\EngineProject\FileSystem.obj  1

Thanks !

Comment: I added the cpp file in the project, no problem with that

Comment: Yes i check that bro and its not that, did i need to link something to use shellapi.h ?

Comment: Then add Shell32.lib to the linker options

Comment: yeah that was that thanks

Comment: The linker error points at ShellExecute. So, if you create a dll, then the linker does not see it in you dll project. If it is the same project, see if the lib is available in all types of settings.

Comment: If you have a single project but switch the project configurations, then you should assure that needed settings are available in new configurations.